# Appcelerator Titanium facebook send specific content

Tags: facebook, titanium, appcelerator, send

I am trying to send some specific content from my Application to the user's status wall.

Lets assume that the user already logged in to facebook through my app - And lets say that my app displays a lot of jokes and riddles. A user finds a joke and he/she wants to publish the joke to his/hers facebook profile (Or even send it through SMS too? (Just a side question, not important))!

How is this possible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Construct a JSON object with [the appropriate Graph API fields](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) corresponding to your joke, and send it to the Graph API using an [XHR requestWithGraphPath](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Facebook-module). For text messages, you might take a look at [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com/).